# How to find out what functions are being called in a site that uses javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I run viral video ads on my sites. I've been trying to detect state changes so that I can have my system respond to it accordingly. The only problem is that I don't have access to the swf object. The ad code is javascript and I am trying to find what calls are being made so that I can try listen to the event as well.

Any help, ideas, code snippets and links are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Use firebug for that: https://getfirebug.com/javascript

Answer (score 0):

If the java script methods are static then you can manipulate them so they will dispatch an event for you, if not you are doomed :/ there would be nothing you can do without changing the site source code.

[Javascript Static methodes](http://justjs.org/js-oop/static-methods-in-javascript/)